# Is there any documentation for the "Feelings" feature in a Facebook status?

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, documentation, status

I have an HTML page where you can update your status via any App ID, and I'm just wondering if there's any documentation for the "Feelings" feature that they've recently added? I'd love to add that feature into my page.

I couldn't find anything relative to this question anywhere, so let me ask this here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The feature to express emotions is not available to third party developers as of this date. It is still being rolled out to the public.

It is built off Open Graph actions (e.g. feeling) and objects (e.g. happy), so I imagine this will come out in the later months.

Comment: Okay, I'll keep an eye out. Thank you. :)

Comment: Do you guys know if that feature has become available for third party developers yet?

Comment: @JamesLaurenstin no, it has not.

Comment: @phwd Any way of handling the pre-defined message + feeling (?)