# Get travelling destination from Facebook using Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

We can share how we are doing or feeling on facebook.
[image: Travelling status update]

In case of travelling, I want to know where the user is travelling to, for example, `London, United Kingdom`.
I tried `https://graph.facebook.com/v2.1/10204187791369437_10204188069976402`. But there is no data about destination.

```
{
  "id": "10204187791369437_10204188069976402",
  "from": {
    "id": "10204187791369437",
    "name": "Sarowar Alam"
  },
  "actions": [
    {
      "name": "Comment",
      "link": "https://www.facebook.com/10204187791369437/posts/10204188069976402"
    },
    {
      "name": "Like",
      "link": "https://www.facebook.com/10204187791369437/posts/10204188069976402"
    }
  ],
  "privacy": {
    "description": "Public",
    "value": "EVERYONE",
    "friends": "",
    "networks": "",
    "allow": "",
    "deny": ""
  },
  "type": "status",
  "status_type": "mobile_status_update",
  "created_time": "2014-10-21T08:24:27+0000",
  "updated_time": "2014-10-21T09:48:53+0000",
  "likes": {
    "data": [
    ],
    "paging": {
      "cursors": {
        "after": "MTAyMDUxMDIzOTgyNjg5NTU=",
        "before": "NDc1Njg3Nzg1NTY1NA=="
      }
    }
  },
  "comments": {
    "data": [
    ],
    "paging": {
      "cursors": {
        "after": "WTI5dGJXVnVkRjlqZFhKemIzSTZNVEF5TURReE9EZ3lPVEV3TmpFNU1qazZNVFF4TXpnNE5Ea3pNem95",
        "before": "WTI5dGJXVnVkRjlqZFhKemIzSTZNVEF5TURReE9EZ3dPVGMyT1Rjd09UVTZNVFF4TXpnNE1EVTNOem94"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Is there any way to do it?

Comment: i highly doubt that it´s possible to read those kind of sensitive data with the graph api. if an app knows where the user is travelling to, it also knows that he is not at home.

Comment: But app can read the place(if available) from where the status is posted. So app would know that he is not at home.

Comment: @sarowar, should my answer satisfy you, may you mark it as accepted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Travelling" is part of the "[Feeling](https://www.facebook.com/help/427780037309149)" feature available when posting on Facebook.

As also answered in [Is there any documentation for the "Feelings" feature in a Facebook status?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16963288/is-there-any-documentation-for-the-feelings-feature-in-a-facebook-status), the data about feelings is just **not available** through the Facebook API, either Graph API or FQL.

Therefore, it's not either possible to know what a user is eating, drinking, watching or listening to.

*PS: it is always risky to add a bounty on questions dealing with API features, since most of the time the API just doesn't provide the features the developers would like. Sorry.*

Comment: I expect the "Life Event" (see http://imgur.com/H6z42bq) thingamabob is just a rebranding of this "Feeling" concept and is equally unaccessible through the API? (And having a confirmation that it's not available is worth a bounty to me. "No" is an answer too. :))

Comment: Just checked and you are right. We can't get any location from the life event posts.

Comment: Great! (Or well, not. :))